# What does the argument "--add" mean in the "git config" command?

Tags: git, bash, terminal, git-bash

I've stumbled across a git command:

```
git config --global --add merge.ff false
```

Presumably it disables fast-forwarding by default when merging branches. But the `--add` option caught my eyes, so I'm now wondering what does it do exactly. Anyone?

Comment: RTFM link [`here`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/git-config/)...

Comment: Thanks, that's a bit unclear to not so advanced users though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [documented in the manual page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html), the `--add` flag tells `git config` not to overwrite any existing `merge.ff` setting, but rather to add a new one in addition to any existing setting.

Since `merge.ff` is not a multi-valued configurable, this is generally the wrong thing to do.  (In fact, due to the way Git scans the configuration file, a newly added setting overrides any previous setting, and `--add` adds at the end, so it works anyway.)  For single-value configuration items like `merge.ff` there really should just be one entry in any given config file.

(Think of it as, for instance, telling Git not to do something, followed by telling it to do something, followed by telling it not to do the thing.  Git simply obeys the *last* command it heard, in this case.)

An example of a multi-valued configuration item is the `fetch` line for each remote.  For instance, `remote.origin.fetch` is normally just `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`, but you might *add* `+refs/notes/*:refs/notes/*` or `+refs/notes/*:refs/notes/origin/*` to copy notes from `origin`, for instance.  (You would definitely not want to remove the first setting, just to add a second one.)

(This is not a bash-specific thing but rather a Git-specific thing.  Bash just runs the command with the specified arguments, and leaves the interpretation of those arguments up to the command.)

Comment: Sorry, still baffled... So does the `--add` flag mean, that all this config setting will descend to all git config scopes (global, repository, branch)?

Comment: No.  Try `git config --global --add foo.bar first`, then examine your global `.gitconfig` (`git config --global --edit` for instance).  Then `git config --global --add foo.bar second`, and examine your global `.gitconfig` again.  Each `--add` puts another line into the file.  Without `--add` the command replaces the existing setting, or fails if there are multiple settings in that file.

Comment: Incidentally, if you set `merge.ff` to `false` in your `--global` settings, and then set it to `true` in your `--local` settings, the local value overrides the global value. The way Git actually implements this is that it scans your global configuration first, then scans your local configuration. Items that accumulate, like `remote.origin.fetch`, will take values from *both* files, but for items like `merge.ff`, that only use a single value, the last setting overrides. Since the local config is read last, any setting there overrides the global config.

Comment: Last, note that when you run `git config --global --edit`, you can make any changes you like to your git configuration.  I'm not sure if Git allows CR-LF endings on Windows systems (I avoid Windows to avoid all its aggravations); editing a config file on a Unix-like machine works fine, and I prefer to use this method for complex items like alias definitions.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful. Got it! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

From the [git-config doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config):

> `--add`
>
> Adds a new line to the option without altering any existing values. This is the same as providing ^$ as the value_regex in --replace-all.